# Old NFC reader-writer program fails building because of Gradle/old android-apt

Tags: android, gradle, android-apt

I had an old application which was an NFC Card content editor. It was working fine, in older versions of android, but i want to update it to be compatible with newer versions. I only know the basics of the plugins which are new, but i saw an article about it, but im not quite sure how that works

[Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268938/errorandroid-apt-plugin-is-incompatible-with-the-android-gradle-plugin-please)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you have trouble replacing the plugins? You should post parts of `build.gradle` with plugins and maybe dependencies

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.